# Getting AngularJS [$injector:modulerr] even when code is correct

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As the title suggests, I keep getting an `[$injector:modulerr]` even with syntactically correct AngularJS code.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/rk2uvmeu/20/)

I'm not sure what's going on here. Am I overlooking something?

The full error message:

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)

(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38

(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4630

q @ angular.js:322g @ angular.js:4591d

b @ angular.js:4513

Ac.c @ angular.js:1777Ac @ angular.js:1798

fe @ angular.js:1683

(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31018

i @ jquery.min.js:2

j.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2

n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2

K @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Just added the full error message text above.

Comment: Do the script includes in your html match up to the injection in your angular.module declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems with your code. 
**First:** You missed the `ng-app` tag. 
**Second:** You missed the `ng-controller` tag.

And the problem with fiddle is that you need to load angular by clicking in "Javascript" and selecting the framework from there and not including it as an external resource. 
[image]

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfau15m9/)

Comment: That's good, but it doesn't resolve the `[$injector:modulerr]` issue when I use your code inside an HTML document. The content will not display correctly, either.

Comment: @Thassa I couldn't get what you mean. You've linked an fiddle that didn't work and I forked it and posted in my answer. My fiddle is exactly the same as yours (corrected with ng-tags) and the error `[$injector:modulerr]` doesn't happens anymore. What are you trying to do? Could you please give more details?

Comment: Never mind, forgot to reload the work environment I was working in. Problem resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it is a problem with JSFiddle, I copied and pasted everything onto Codepen and it worked as expected. Only difference was Copdepen was using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue with getting jsfiddle to actually run angularJS recently. That being said I ran it in plunker and you need to add `ng-app="app"` to the body or surrounding div. and `ng-controller="appCtrl"` That should work. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zUXnNNKWo7I1CGqeASqP?p=preview) for reference.